# Softaculous start symfony app

Tags: php, symfony, ampps, softaculous

So i have downloaded Softaculous (ampps), and from their dashboard I  installed the symfony framework, and it created a symfony3 folder with all of the files in the www directory (with an index.php file in the root directory of symfony that only prints a welcome message).

When I access it through http://localhost/symfony3/ it shows the index.php (if i remove the index.php it just shows the tree of the symfony3 directory)

Is it possible to set my localhost to launch the app? If I run `php bin/console server:start` it launches my app on localhost with port 8000. Is it possible to set up Ampps to launch my app when it is accessed through localhost/symfony3/ ? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So turns out I could do this just by editing the httpd70.conf file (ampps>conf>httpd70.conf)

find the `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` block and change the `<Directory "{$path}/www">` to the web folder in your app (in my case it was `<Directory "{$path}/www/symfony3/web">` and do the same thing for `DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"` in the same block. Restart your Apache. You should now see your app when you just go to http://localhost/ (http://localhost/app_dev.php/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need to set up you web server with correct configuration file and to change permissions for Symfony project.

It might be helpful (documentation for Symfony 2.8.*):

1. [Web server configuration.](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/web_server_configuration.html)
2. [Symfony project file permissions.](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: yes, I was thinking that for softaculous ampps it needs to be installed differently, turns out that was wrong. will update my question with an answer